# Can we automate the changes which we are manually doing in SharePoint designer workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Firstly sorry if the question was weird. I had a 80 similar lists and each and every list had a workflow. Now i had a change in the list and based on that i need to add a condition in designer workflow. can we automate the changes which we need to do in the workflow instead of changing manually in all the 80 workflows. Please refer me if there is any solution regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider creating a reusable workflow, meaning you would only need to manage one workflow.

[SharePoint 2013: Create Reusable Workflow on Content Type using SharePoint Designer 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, i will check with the solution